# Model fitting functions and environemnts

Tags: r, scoping

Here is a kind of minimal example for a problem I stumbled upon:

```
mylm <- function(formula,data,subset=NULL){
  mysubset <- subset # some other clever manipulation
  lm(formula,data,mysubset)
}
mydata <- data.frame(x=rnorm(10),y=rnorm(10))
mylm(y~x,mydata) # this fails!
```

The reason why the last line fails is, that `lm` contains a call to `model.frame`, which is evaluated in the `parent.frame`, i.e. `lm` contains the line of code

```
mf <- eval(mf, parent.frame())
```

Here the `mf` on the right side is a cleverly constructed call to `model.frame`. I am passing on `mysubset`, but `eval` looks for it (I believe, but correct me if I am wrong) in the basic environment and doesn't find it. I know that I could probably use `lm.fit`, but is there a way to make the environment inside `mylm` the `parent.frame` for `lm`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you are right, the call to `model.frame` (actually, `model.frame.default`) is looking for `mysubset` in the `.GlobalEnv`. However, a better generalization would be to say that it is trying to evaluate various objects either in the object passed to `data` or, if they are not there, in the environment of the `formula` that you pass to it. And that environment is the `.GlobalEnv`.

So `model.frame.default` calls

```
eval(substitute(subset), data, env)
```

That translates to "evaluate the object `mysubset` in `data` or, if not there, in `env` (which is `environment(formula)`).

One way to get around this is to recreate your formula inside your function, where it will assume the environment created when your function is called, where `mysubset` exists:

```
mylm <- function(formula,data,subset=NULL){
  mysubset <- subset # some other clever manipulation
  lm(formula(deparse(formula)),data,subset=mysubset)
}
```

In that way, `model.frame.default` should be able to find `mysubset`.